# Generate property internal set

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Pq que a partir da versão do Visual Studio 2015 toda vez que mando gerar um atributo em uma classe o mesmo está gerando com o `set` `internal`?
Nas versões anteriores o VS gerava como `public`.

Comment: Isso acontece quando você usa o atalho `prop`?

Comment: quando uso o `Ctrl+.`

Comment: Boa sorte: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32232135/221800 :)

Comment: Pelo que entendi lá, seria que para alguns desenvolvedores é interessante que gere como `internal`?

Comment: Acredito que seja assim por você ter criado a propriedade utilizando o `CTRL +` dentro do mesmo projeto, ai por questões de privacidade de definição da propriedade o `VS` coloca como internal. Acho que se criar em outro projeto deve vir como `public`. Deve ser possível modificar esse comportamento alterando algum template do `VS`, mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: Pois é, lembro que no 2013 ele gerava as classes sem o public, ai editei um template pra sempre adicionar o public, só que pra gerar a propriedade eu não achei qual o template que tenho que alterar.

Answer (score 0):

Depende de onde você está querendo criar essa propriedade, e também do formato da nomenclatura.

```
public class Teste
{
    public Teste()
    {
        minhaProriedade = 1; // private readonly 
        OutraPropriedade = true; // public
    }

    public Metodo()
    {
        MaisUmaProp = "OK"; // como private, internal ou protected, se tiver herança
    }
}
```

E assim vai, dependendo de onde irá partir a criação da propriedade, o Visual Studio vai tentar adivinhar o nível de segurança da mesma.