# TextBoxFor retornado Null Post

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Eu tenho um form em que eu faço uma consulta a uma API usando jquery. A consulta retorna os dados e preencho os textboxfor com estes dados :

```
 $.getJSON("//viacep.com.br/ws/" + cep + "/json/?callback=?", function (dados) {

                if (!("erro" in dados)) {
                    //Atualiza os campos com os valores da consulta.

                    $("#Logradouro").val(dados.logradouro);
                    $("#Bairro").val(dados.bairro);
                    $("#Cidade").val(dados.localidade);
                    $('#Estado option[value="' + dados.uf + '"]').attr({ selected: "selected" });

                }

<div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Cidade)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.Cidade, new { @class = "form-control rounded", @placeholder = "Cidade do Condutor" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Cidade, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
```

```html
 [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Add(CondutorViewModel condutor)
        {

           
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(condutor);
            }

            var result = CondutorRepositoryUI.GetInstance().AddOrUpdate(condutor);

            TempData["AtualizacaoCondutor"] = result.Mensagem;

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Quando eu faço o POST para o formulário os campos que foram preenchidos pelo jquery retornam null, embora apareçam na tela os demais campos que foram digitados aparecem normal.

Comment: Pode editar sua resposta colocando como está seu Controller?

Comment: Fiz a edição colocando o controller.

Comment: Qual é o escopo do `<form/>`? Usando ferramentas de desenvolvimento do browser, o que está sendo enviado para sua controler a partir do browser?

Comment: Colocando um *breakpoint* sobre `var result = CondutorRepositoryUI.GetInstance().AddOrUpdate(condutor);`, como estão preenchidas as propriedades de `condutor`?

Comment: Todos os demais campos retornam o valor normalmente, mas os campos preenchidos pelo jquery retornam null.

Answer (score 1):

O que imagino que aconteceu no seu caso.

A partir da versão 2015 do Visual Studio ao usarmos o `intellisense` para gerar uma propriedade na `ViewModel`, o VS está gerando como `internal set`, já procurei formas de evitar do VS gerar o set da propriedade como [`internal`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125202/generate-property-internal-set), mas não obtive nenhuma resposta satisfatória, a solução encontrado por mim é sempre procurar em toda solução, usando o  Ctrl+Shift+F, por `internal set` e substituir por `public set`.

Na imagem 1 mostro como fica com `internal set`
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public class CondutorViewModel
    {
        public string Cep { get; internal set; }
        public string Cidade { get; internal set; }
        public string Logradouro { get; internal set; }
        public string Estado { get; internal set; }
        public string Bairro { get; internal set; }
    }
```

Na imagem 2 mostro como fica com `public set`
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como fica o Model

```
public class CondutorViewModel
    {
        public string Cep { get; set; }
        public string Cidade { get; set; }
        public string Logradouro { get; set; }
        public string Estado { get; set; }
        public string Bairro { get; set; }    
    }
```